# How can I run rpm and yum on RHEL?

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

I'm trying to do some debugging on my remote server via SSH. I need to install a few packages before I begin. The provider I'm using has Red Hat Linux on their servers.

The problem I'm having is that I can't install packages at all. When I try to run yum, I get the following message:

> yum: command not found.

I tried to resolve this by using wget to get the yum rpm. I attempted to to install the yum rpm, but this didn't work either. When I used rpm in bash, I got:

> rpm: command not found

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: What does the output of `echo $PATH` and `find / -name rpm -print` give you?

Comment: Is the system [managed by cpanel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=cpanel+yum)?

Comment: Yes the system is managed by cpanel.  `echo $PATH` gives: >/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/[domain]/.local/bin:/home/[domain]/bin

Comment: and `find / -name rpm -print` gives a long list of paths with "permission denied"

Comment: https://de.godaddy.com/community/cPanel-Hosting/no-apt-or-yum-commands/td-p/90568

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm going to go ahead and post an answer to my own question. This has nothing to do with RHEL itself or any kind of bug. It is intended behavior.

Based on the comments from Thomas and Jeff Schaller, it looks like it is not possible to use `yum` or `rpm`. The problem is that shared hosting environment is very restricted, and only allows some basic functionality. Most significantly, the hosting service does not allow root access and does not support package installation.

The workaround in this case was to simply write a debugging function in PHP which opens a socket to the required remote hosts to test connectivity and authentication, and outputs the responses to certain requests made by the server.